# Expresso Store Inline Errors Not Working

Tags: expresso-store

I'm using Expresso Store 1.6.4 and EE 2.6.0.  The inline errors are not working, the page just refreshes to the site homepage.  If I remove the inline errors, the default EE error page displays correctly.

I'll just mention that we're also using Boldmindeds Publisher on this site as well, which has caused some issues on other parts of the site, so that could be an explanation.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you included all the fields that are required in your store tag [as per the docs](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#require) along with the actual `{error:field_name}` tags for each field? Also, have you tried to disable Publisher to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Just checking to see if you've managed to resolve this issue? Quite often this is a minor glitch in the templates somewhere. If you still need help then feel free to email support@exp-resso.com and we'll take a look.

Comment: Hi Ian, everything looks ok with the code, error fields have all be included.  I suspect it was publisher that was causing it, but just wanted to check if you had any ideas.  We just styled the default EE error page and that's working fine for the client.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like it is being caused by Publisher. If you disable Publisher, does the problem go away?

If so, it's probably best to contact BoldMinded so they can investigate the issue directly.